# Out of range when creating a matrix whose sizes are sizes of two other matrices

Tags: c++, vector, size

Let's suppose I have two matrices called A and B and I want to make  a new matrix C where the number of rows of C is equal to the product of number of rows of matrices A and B. The number of columns of C is also equal to the product of the number of columns of A and B.

My program does NOT work when any of the matrices A or B is an empty matrix.

I tried setting the size of the matrices A and B to something different than zero, the program worked.

```
  // this function "creates" and returns a matrix of the size mentioned in parameters



 vector<vector<int>> CreateMatrix (int number_of_rows, int number_of_columns) {
  return vector<vector<int>>(number_of_rows, vector<int> (number_of_columns));
 } 

  int main()
  {
    vector<vector<int>> a;
    vector<vector<int>> b;
    int no_rows = a.size() * b.size(); // multiplies no. of rows A and B
    int no_cols = a.at(0).size() * b.at(0).size(); // multiplies number of columns of A and B

   auto c = CreateMatrix(no_rows, no_cols).
   cout << c.size();
```

I expected that the program prints "0" because that would be the number of rows of the matrix C, but rather than doing that it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
    vector<vector<int>> a;
    vector<vector<int>> b;
    int no_cols = a.at(0).size() * b.at(0).size(); // multiplies number of columns of A and B
```

Here you access first elements of two empty vectors, so naturally it crashes.

Comment: Hmm..now that I pay attention to it, you're absolutely right. Would it be considered hardcoding if I checked for a condition if either of the sizes of two matrices was 0, the program should return just an empty matrix? Can you suggest an alternative? Thanks very much

Comment: If either of them is empty, then naturally the result should be empty (its both dimensions zero) so simply check both operands for emptiness and return an empty matrix if true.

Comment: Thanks a million times man! I can't believe i overlooked something that simple